# Proper format of Procfile for Flask App on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I'm trying to deploy a flask app on heroku. I've gotten to the point where the app builds and deploys, but when I try to go to the URL, the app times out with the following error.

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

I think the problem is with my procfile. It has one line.

```
web: python add_entry3.py
```

Other people have procfiles that look like this:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

This is just a toy app and I don't care about performance so I don't think I need to use gunicorn for the web server. Should I be putting a colon and command after my app's file name (add_entry3.py)?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your flask app isn't answering on the port and interface the Heroku expects. By default, Flask *only* listens on 127.0.0.1, and I think on port 5000. Heroku passes your app a `PORT` environment variable and you'd need to tell Flask to listen on all interfaces.

But there are reasons other than performance you want to avoid Flask's default debug server for production code. It's got memory leaks, there are security implications, and really ... just don't do it. Add gunicorn to your requirements.txt and use that.

But if you *must* use the Flask test/debug server, change your `app.run()` call to something like this:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000)))
```