# Flask Deploy to Heroku Error 2019-04-16T09:17:52.610857+00:00 heroku[router]: at:error code:H10 desc:App crashed

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I am trying to deploy a Flask app on Heroku and it keeps crashing

> 2019-04-16T09:17:39.523071+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   crashed to starting 
>   2019-04-16T09:17:43.455032+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Starting process with command `gunicorn run:app`
>   2019-04-16T09:17:45.169493+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   starting to crashed 
>   2019-04-16T09:17:45.145760+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Process exited with status 1

this is my procfile

```
web: gunicorn run:app
```

This is my run.py

```
from my_project import create_app
app = create_app()
```

This is my my_project/**init**.py

```
def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    return app
```

Any suggestions to fix the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your run file.

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000)))
```

If you want to know more [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787651/proper-format-of-procfile-for-flask-app-on-heroku)